# Adjust Node REPL to not clobber prompt on async callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

When working with the Node [REPL](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) console, I'm looking for a way for asynchronous calls to both not lock up the console input, and not clobber the console prompt when they return.

I've seen a few solutions dealing with asynchronous calls in the REPL, where writing your own custom `eval` function you can check the result of the executed code to see if it's a promise/async object, and just not return until it resolves.

However, I'd like to solve the issue of a repeating background process logging its progress. Ideally I'd like it to behave like the Chrome Javascript console, where if you have a command partially printed on the console prompt, and an async result gets logged, the line you're typing on gets moved one line down, and the log inserted above it.

So, functionally, I'd like to insert the logic that when `console.log()` is called, the line containing the cursor is first cleared, then the contents of the `log()` written, and then the REPL prompt (and whatever the user had typed so far onto it) gets re-written on the line following the new output.

Is there any way to hook into the REPL object to accomplish this? Is this some advanced manipulation of the output stream from the REPL (i.e. only possible on terminals that support an "erase to beginning of line" escape code)?

Comment: not sure about js solutions, but you can press up to get your line back. you can also use console.error() instead of log() so that your messages go out over stdErr instead of stdOut. if you split the prompt output, you can redirect stdError to a log file or null, keeping your repl stdOut-only and hopefully un-interrupted.

Comment: @dandavis: Pressing "up" gets the command entered previously; it doesn't re-enter the fragment of a command you were in the middle of typing. I did discover if you press `delete` it does redraw the line you were working on (minus one character). Now if only I could tap into that event that's redrawing on backspace....

Answer (score 1):

Tapping straight into the Output Stream I managed to get something working like how I wanted:

```
var server = repl.start({
    prompt: '> '
});
server.context.console.log = function(msg) {
    var rli = server.rli;
    server.outputStream.write('\033[2K\033[1G'); // Erase to beginning of line, and reposition cursor at beginning of line
    server.outputStream.write(msg+"\n");
    server.outputStream.write(''+rli._prompt+rli.line); // Redraw existing line
    server.outputStream.write('\033['+(rli.cursor+rli._promptLength+1)+'G'); // Move the cursor to where it was
}

server.context.doTimeout = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        server.context.console.log('Timeout done!');
    }, 2000);
};
```

Though that all assumes an ANSI-compliant output stream is the output, and feels quite hack-ish, overriding the `console.log()` function like that. Is there a more compliant way to handle this, or is this the best way?

Comment: Write your own custom logging function that writes to your output stream (console.log in node is just a simple fn that writes to process.stdout directly with a \n) and call that instead of console.log.  You are going to need to use the ANSI escape codes to achieve what you want, but overriding console.log isn't necessary

Answer (score 1):

Still, now I cannot find a modern satisfactory answer on StackOverflow.
After spending a few hours on the internet, I came up with this solution for latest Node (v15.*)

```
const log = (msg) => {
  rl.output.write('\r')
  rl.output.write(msg + '\n')
  rl.displayPrompt(true)
}
```

Basically, clear the line, write the log, then display the prompt again. Works perfectly for my case.

Improved solution.
The above works well if the buffered line is not longer than the log. So here is another version that pad the rest of log by space characters

```
const log = (msg) => {
  rl.output.write('\r');
  rl.output.write(_.padEnd(msg, process.stdout.columns - 2, ' ') + '\n');
  rl.displayPrompt(true);
};
```

- _.padEnd: lodash's padEnd, can be replaced by any lib

Answer (score 0):

Based on @MidnightLightning's older answer.

As of sometime before node v12.15.0 the console.log override would look like:

```
activeRepl.context.console.log = (msg) => {
  const promptOffset = Server._prompt.length + Server.line.length;
  Server.outputStream.write('\033[2K\033[1G'); // Erase to beginning of line, and reposition cursor at beginning of line
  Server.outputStream.write(msg + "\n");
  Server.outputStream.write('' + Server._prompt + Server.line); // Redraw existing line
  Server.outputStream.write('\033[' + (promptOffset + 1) + 'G'); // Move the cursor to where it was
};
```